# How to fix getGCF recursion program?

Tags: java

So I am writing this getGCF program that uses Euclid's steps to find the GCF of two numbers, and I am using recursion to try and make this work but for some reason even when the correct GCF seems to be obtained 1 is returned. I'm not sure how I would fix this but any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
public static int getGCF(int num1, int num2){

    int gcf=1;
    int remainder = num1%num2;

    if(remainder == 0){
       gcf = num2;

    }
    else{
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = remainder;
        getGCF(num1,num2);
    }

    return gcf;
}
```

Comment: Try `return getGCF(num1,num2)` when recursing.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm sorry, I don't understand recursion perfectly well, I know about it, but I must've made a recursing mistake. Thank you, that helped. Here's the improved code :) : 

`public static int getGCF(int num1, int num2){
  
  int gcf=1;
  int remainder = num1%num2;
  
  if(remainder == 0){
     gcf = num2;
     return gcf;
   
  }
  else{
   num1 = num2;
   num2 = remainder;
   return getGCF(num1,num2);
  }
  
  //return getGCF(num1,num2);
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that your else clause doesn't modify the gcf int even though it computes the correct value. Here is condensed code that fixes your issue. By returning in the if/else statements themselves, you eliminate the need for the gcf variable.

```
public static int getGCF(int num1, int num2) {
    int remainder = num1 % num2;

    if(remainder == 0) {
       return num2;
    } else {
        return getGCF(num2, remainder);
    }
}
```

Although potentially unrelated, it's worth nothing that there are some edge cases this won't handle (such as when num2 is 0).